# How to write in more nice way or according PEP8 style

Tags: python, numpy

I have a lot of columns where I want to replace null with zero. Is there any way to write it in a more proper way or how to set the line breaks or the indents to make it more readable?

```
df[["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5", "column6", "column7", "column8", "column9", "column10", "column11", "column12"]] = np.where(dfdf[["column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5", "column6", "column7", "column8", "column9", "column10", "column11", "column12"]].isnull(), 0, 1)
```

Comment: you can use tools like black, pylint, poetry

Comment: Or use autopep8 which will automatically reformat your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add on drawbu answer, in this scenario I would try to improve readability by using:

```
columns_to_filter = [
    "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5", "column6", 
    "column7", "column8", "column9", "column10", "column11", "column12"
]

df[columns_to_filter] = np.where(dfdf[columns_to_filter].isnull(), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
df[[
    "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5", "column6", 
    "column7", "column8", "column9", "column10", "column11", "column12"
]] = np.where(
    dfdf[[
        "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5", "column6", 
        "column7", "column8", "column9", "column10", "column11", "column12"
    ]].isnull(), 
    0, 
    1
)
```

It's not perfect, but far more readable, and following PEP8 style.
Split your lines if it exceeds 80 characters (some people prefer 120, your choice). And if you do it for one argument of the call, consider doing it for all, to not create some irregularity.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using pandas, you may be able to use a [`filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) to select the subset of columns that you want to modify. In your simple case, you could also use a list comprehension.

Instead of `isnull` + `np.where`, I'd go for [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html) + [`astype(int)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = ... # Your df here

# Solution:
cols = [ f"column{i}" for i in range(1, 13) ]
df[cols] = df[cols].notna().astype(int)
```